# Фильтрация товаров по категории catalog.smart.filter bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс, filter

Есть умный фильтр smart.filter в комплексном каталоге bitrix.catalog, в фильтре выводятся свойства товаров, а как в этот фильтр добавить категории товаров, чтобы можно было фильтровать по ним?
Примерно догадываюсь что как-то в template.php в $GLOBALS['FILTER_NAME'] => MAX_SMART_FILTER нужно добавить массив категорий и их свойств (или не так?), который можно получить как-то так:

```
CIBlockSection::GetList(array(), array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ACTIVE'=>'Y', 'SECTION_ID'=>$IBLOCK_SECTION_ID, '!ID' => $arParams['SECTION_ID'] ), false, array("SECTION_PAGE_URL", 'NAME', 'ID', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID', 'DEPTH_LEVEL'));
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, или пните в нужном направлении?

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то будет интересно, вот, добрый человек поделился реализацией: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-a-16XxOmOw
уж сколько я облазил, искал по запросу в интернете нет ничего и не находит ничего, даже не знаю, почему мне не попадалась эта ссылка на ютуб...